# Ellipsize text before and after my string [React Native]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

As the title mentions, I'm trying to find a way to ellipsis an array of string. I first thought about using the property `tail` and `head` from the `ellipsizeMode`  property but it says that I can only use one at a time. Any idea of how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the character limit you have

```
render(){
const maxLimit=38 //for example
const myText=arrayString.join(" ");

return(
    <Text>
          {myText.length > maxLimit
            ? '...' +
              myText.substring(
                myText.length / 2 - maxLimit / 2,
                myText.length / 2 + maxLimit / 2,
              ) + '...'
            : myText}
     </Text>
);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about doing it that way but was hoping for something related to the property ellipsizeMode. I guess there aren't many alternatives to it , thanks I appreciate your help